# How to deploy maven-plugin on GitLab

Tags: java, maven, deployment, gitlab-ci, maven-plugin

I have a private Maven multi-module project hosted on GitLab. Now I decided to start creating versions of modules. When module has set **packaging** to *jar* or *pom*, the module is properly deployed to GitLab and version with it's tag is generated. But modules with **packaging** set to *maven-plugin*, because they are custom created Maven plugins, fails in deployment stage.
First I though that this custom *maven-plugins* can not be released together with other "normal" modules, but this was false assumption. Even I try to release only this one project only with *maven-plugin*, deployment fails.

Here is an error message with a reason why it fails:

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0:deploy (default-deploy) on project XXX: Failed to deploy metadata: Could not transfer metadata XXX from/to gitlab-maven (https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/xxxxxxxx/packages/maven): status code: 400, reason phrase: Bad Request (400) -> [Help 1]

I do not quite understand why this is happening, because I'm using exactly same configuration for my other modules and it's working correctly. Also if I just change **packaging** from *maven-plugin* to *jar*, than deployment is successful. So connection configuration should not be an issue.

Does anyone have experience with custom maven-plugin deployment on GitLab? I can provide **pom.xml** if necessary, but it mostly follows the documentation regarding to configuration for deployment.

Many thanks,
Petr

Comment: The 400 often means that you cannot deploy because either the artifact is already there, or the repository does only take Snapshots, but you deploy a Release (or vice versa).

Comment: Well, it's an interesting idea, but I can deploy a release of module if it has packaging set to jar or pom. Only issue is with maven-plugin. Also I'm sure the artifact does not exists, because there are no artifacts.